# Apply code to dynamically loaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where an image with a wrapping div gets loaded via ajax. I need to apply some code when that image is loaded. **I cannot alter the ajax call** so **I cannot** simply use `on('success')` on the ajax call.
After some time the image with the div gets reloaded the same way (it is a kind of rotation).

The structure is like this:

```
<div id="spot">
    <div id="xyz">
        <a href="http://someurl.com">
            <img src="http://someimage.url" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "spot" div is fixed and everything inside of it gets loaded dynamically.

When I put in

```
$('#xyz img').on('load', myCallback);
```

It doesn't work, I think because when the image gets reloaded, the listener is also removed.

I tried with the delegated listener:

```
$('#spot').on('load', '#xyz img', myCallback);
```

but didn't work either, it doesn't get executed (I've put console.log inside to verify what happens).

When I type in console `$('#spot #xyz > img')` the console shows the correct object.

**How can I run my `myCallback` function right after the dynamic content with the image is ready for some DOM scripting action?**

Comment: A `load` event is not raised for `div` elements. Why can't you amend the AJAX request? It's bar *far* the most simple and elegant solution here. I guess you could use a MutationObserver, but they aren't well supported in older browsers. What is the code you need to apply? If it's event handlers you could just delegate them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the ajax call is 3rd party, so I cannot alter it. I need to dynamically remove the link of the image and apply an image map instead, that's what I do in `myCallback` and is actually working, but only when it is called right after the image is there.

Comment: But surely that third party AJAX call has a callback you can use...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan assume I cannot hook into the ajax call. It's not helpful telling me to use something that I dont have.

Comment: Well, your workarounds are a `setInterval` timer, a MutationObesrver or a `load` event handler on an `img` element that's loaded by the AJAX request (although this will only fire *after* the image loads, not when the element is added to the DOM so there will be a delay). None of these are ideal, nor elegant. I would suggest you spend more time looking at how to get access to the callback. It would be worth it in the long term.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are absolutely right but the code ain't easy and very much uglyfied. Tried MutationObserver now and it's sufficient and working well! If give a quick answer with that I'd accept that.

Comment: No problem, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get access to the AJAX request callback then your options are limited to a `setInterval()` timer which checks to see if the elements have been added, a MutationObserver or a `load` event on an `img` element - but be aware this will only fire after the `src` of the image has loaded so there will be a delay.

Here's how you can use the `MutationObserver`, but be aware this will only work for newer browsers:

```
var targetElement = document.querySelector('#container');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // perform the required actions here...
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
});

observer.observe(targetElement, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the correct way but you can try this

```
var handle = setInterval(showImage, 500);

function showImage(e) {
    var img = $('#spot').find("img");
    if(img != undefined) {
         if($(img).is(":visible")) {
              clearInterval(handle);
              handle = 0;
              // your logic
         }
    }
}
```